# Alignment of "Page" in List of Figures in LaTeX

Tags: latex, text-alignment

I'm writing my masters thesis in LaTeX and having trouble getting the "Page" at the top of the list of figures aligned with the left of the page numbers, as shown below.  It's pretty close, but needs to move a few pixels to the right.  I'm using the tocloft package.  Anyone have any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

[image]

Comment: This should instead be asked at the dedicated stack exchange site for LaTeX questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out kind of by random luck.  There's a newline in the LaTeX code that seems to make a difference, but I'm not sure exactly why.

Broken version:

```
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{
\\[4em]\mbox{}\hspace{2pt}FIGURE \hfill{\normalfont Page}
}
```

Fixed version:

```
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{
\\[4em]\mbox{}\hspace{2pt}FIGURE \hfill{\normalfont Page}}
```